# how to get telephone number from google by submitting company name and address?

Tags: delphi

A customer asked me a simple app that retrieves the telephone number given the full address of a company.

So imagine a simple edit box where I type

*Dummy Company ltd - 143, High Road, 519243 DummyCity, DU - DummyCountry*

and I ask "google" or something else and I get the telephone number as answer.

Of course I need to do this for many customers at once, but if I can do it for 1 it is easy to extend.

Did anyone already implemented something like this?

Comment: Don't you need to buy the telephone directory database?

Comment: the customer bought a special database that contains many info about the customers but there is no phone or mail information, this info is needed to make very specific direct marketings, but unfortunately no phone info there. Of course one can manually search but it takes too much. This is why he asked me to create this app.

Comment: Take this link http://google.about.com/od/googlebasics/qt/phonebook.htm as a signpost

Comment: @daemon_x the link you provided starts with this: This was always an undocumented feature, `and it appears it is now gone and no longer works`, just for your own info.

Comment: Sorry, forget on the previous post, it seems, they've cancelled this option at all, so it IMHO won't be so easy

Comment: @jachguate +1, you were faster :) So maybe Google Maps can help

Comment: Why don't you buy the telephone numbers as well as the company details?

Comment: @user193655, forget Delphi. If you enter <whatever> in Google, can you immediately spot the phone number? Or do you need to use your own intelligence to select the correct Google result, then look over the page looking for some sort of "Contact" page where one might (or might not) find an phone number? This whole process looks like something that can't be automated.

Comment: How do you determine what is a telephone number? There might be other numbers on a company site. And when you get the number how do you no it's relevant? Not some salesperson or helpdesk number or whatever phone numbers that can be found.

Comment: Ok, probably what I was looking for is exactly what daemon_x suggested, feature that is not available anymore as @jachguate pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try to contact the "yellow pages" in your region and ask them, guess they provide such an API, take a look at [the canadian one](http://www.yellowapi.com/) for example

Comment: yes there is no other solution. The db the customer bought is useless, or anyway too similar to manual search, it contained some intersting data but i realize it is very not up to date. Basically he lost money. Yellow pages with or without apis seem anyway more useful.